# How to multiply or divide (N, 50) numpy array with (N, 1) numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
paths.shape
(525600, 50)

T.shape
(525600,)
```

how do I divide or multiply paths by T?

More specifically I want to do this

```
S = pd.DataFrame(paths)

d1 = S.divide(np.sqrt(T), axis=0)
```

but not using pandas

want to use numpy only

Comment: That's not `(N, 1)`. `T` is a one-dimensional array.

Comment: @user2357112 oh I see, ,, ,

Comment: You can use `np.dot()`  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html. Also don't use `T` as variable name when working with matrices. You never know when you might need a transpose of the matrix https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html

Comment: You can add the extra dimensions with `reshape` or something like `t[:, np.newaxis]`. This will allow you to broadcast the multiplication.

Comment: It will also be helpful if you clarify what you mean by multiplying these arrays. What kind of result do you expect? There are multiple ways arrays can be multiplied. Show example with smaller arrays.

Comment: That would help if you advised what shape you expect from `paths*T`....

Answer (score 1):

2 arrays:

```
In [17]: paths = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3); T = np.arange(1,5)    
In [18]: paths.shape, T.shape
Out[18]: ((4, 3), (4,))            # not (4,1)
```

Your pandas approach:

```
In [19]: S = pd.DataFrame(paths)    
In [20]: d1 = S.divide(np.sqrt(T), axis=0)    
In [21]: S
Out[21]: 
   0   1   2
0  0   1   2
1  3   4   5
2  6   7   8
3  9  10  11

In [22]: d1
Out[22]: 
          0         1         2
0  0.000000  1.000000  2.000000
1  2.121320  2.828427  3.535534
2  3.464102  4.041452  4.618802
3  4.500000  5.000000  5.500000
```

That `S.divide` lets you specify an axis.

The wrong `numpy`:

```
In [23]: paths/np.sqrt(T)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [23], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 paths/np.sqrt(T)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,3) (4,)
```

But if we make `T` (4,1):

```
In [24]: paths/np.sqrt(T[:,None])
Out[24]: 
array([[0.        , 1.        , 2.        ],
       [2.12132034, 2.82842712, 3.53553391],
       [3.46410162, 4.04145188, 4.61880215],
       [4.5       , 5.        , 5.5       ]])
```

The key is `broadcasting`.  Size 1 dimensions can be adjusted to match.  Leading size 1 dimensions are automatic, but trailing ones are not.  `(n,)` is a one element tuple (a basic Python expression). There isn't an implicit trailing size 1 dimension.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple different interpretations of your question, one of which may be related to this:

```
paths.transpose()*T
paths.transpose()/np.sqrt(T)
```

Comment: But the result is transposed.